# Firebase database не принимает данные

Tags: java, android, firebase

```
    package com.tekemuradov.aman.ulgmada;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

public class RegisterActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Toolbar mToolbar;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;


    private EditText RegisterUserName;
    private EditText RegisterUserEmail;
    private EditText RegisterUserPassword;
    private Button CreateAccountButton;


    private DatabaseReference storeUserDefaultDataReference;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

        mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.register_toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Registrasiýa");
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        RegisterUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_name);
        RegisterUserEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_email);
        RegisterUserPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.register_password);
        CreateAccountButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.create_account_button);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);

        CreateAccountButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                final String name = RegisterUserName.getText().toString();
                String email = RegisterUserEmail.getText().toString();
                String password = RegisterUserPassword.getText().toString();

                RegisterAccount(name,email,password);
            }
        });

    }

    private void RegisterAccount(final String name, String email, String password) {

        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(name)){

            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,"Adyňyzy giriziň",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){

            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                    "Emailyňyzy giriziň",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){

            Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                    "Parolyňyzy giriziň",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
        else{

            loadingBar.setTitle("Täze sahypa döredilýär");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Garaşmagyňyzy haýyş edýäris");
            loadingBar.show();

            mAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){


                       String current_User_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
                       storeUserDefaultDataReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance()
                               .getReference().child("Users").child(current_User_id);

                       storeUserDefaultDataReference.child("user_name").setValue(name);
                       storeUserDefaultDataReference.child("user_status").setValue("Ulgamda ulanyjy");
                       storeUserDefaultDataReference.child("user_image").setValue("default_profile");
                       storeUserDefaultDataReference.child("user_thumb_image").setValue("default_image")
                               .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                   @Override
                                   public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                       if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                           Intent mainIntent = new Intent(RegisterActivity.this, MainActivity.class);
                                           mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                           startActivity(mainIntent);
                                           finish();
                                       } else {
                                           Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                                                   "Problema synanyşyp görüň",
                                                   Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                       }
                                   }
                               });
                    }
                    else {
                        Toast.makeText(RegisterActivity.this,
                                "Bagyşlaň tazeden synanyşyp görüň",
                                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                    loadingBar.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Я так полагаю, что это связано с тем, что Вы пытаетесь обратиться к базе из основного потока, что в Андроиде фактически запрещено. Для тяжелых процессов необходимо создавать отдельные потоки. Почитайте про `AsyncTask`

Answer (score 0):

Проверьте:
 - в консоли Firebase - DataBase что вы работаете с Realtime Database, а не Cloud Databese;
 - проверьте в Realtime Database правила чтения и записи, что бы без ограничений должно быть так:

```
{ Visit https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security to learn more about security rules.  "rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
```

}
}

Comment: проблема в том что у меня было плохое интернет соединение и я использовал впн сервер чтоб записывать данные Спасибо всем большое